# Filter collection on ThenInclude() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following database structure: a project contains a list of project benchmarks that have a global benchmark comprised of a list of sector benchmarks.

```
project -> project benchmark -> global benchmark -> sector benchmark
```

When writing a query to get all the benchmarks for a project, I need to filter the sector benchmarks by sector id so that I have only those sector benchmarks that correspond with the sector of the project.

I have tried:

```
_dbContext.ProjectBenchmarks
    .Include(b => b.GlobalBenchmark)
        .ThenInclude(gb => gb.SectorBenchmark
        .Where(sb => sb.SectorId == sectorId))
```

but it does not filter the sector benchmarks by the sector id and I get all the sector benchmarks. How could I accomplish this?

**Update**: as per a comment, adding `.ToList()` to this query fixed the issue. Now I need to further the problem I have: This query is inside a `mapper.ProjectTo(<query here>).ToList()`, with the `ToList()` on the outside. How can I filter and use the mapper to map my entities?

Comment: what if you try a  .ToList(); at the end?

Comment: @jeb, that seems to have worked. Now I have to elaborate more of my problem: This query is inside a `mapper.ProjectTo(....).ToList()` that should map my db entities to a DTO. How doen't the filter work in the mapper?

Comment: sorry no idea. based on the code provided i cannot make any statement

Comment: `ProjectTo` discards includes. You have to filter in Mapping Profile which is not possible. So use ProjectTo after `ToList().AsQuerybale().ProjectTo` or use other function which maps local objects.